# ASP.NET MVC route not matched

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

My route registration is as follows:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "course_list",
        "course/list",
        new { controller = "course", action = "list" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "course_view",
        "course/view/{id}",
        new { controller = "course", action = "view", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

I can browse to /course/view/87 and the proper route is matched. When i visit the /course/list page, and click a link on that page that points to /course/view/87, i get a 404: /course/list not found. Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Here is a link to a page that has a button acting as a link: http://hspot.ca/course/list

Comment: ok, whats I see the url rendered. please add the helper code you used to create it.

Comment: Click on the button 'Details" on that page, and the route debugger will show the error

Comment: What do you mean by explain how it resolves?

Comment: add the code that creates this button link to your example. i see the url it leads to. course/view/s  clearly wrong but valid by your route setter.

Comment: <a href="/course/view/87"><button style="float: right; width: 200px;" class="submit">More info</button></a> ............ I hardcoded just to test, I updated the page itself with this

Comment: OK, I see. crazy. Now, the action method view(int id)... does it have a redirect? what kind of actionresult does it return?

Comment: I don't get this... even when the link href is "/course/view" i get a 404... but when i navigate to the url directly from the browser address bar i get no error.

Comment: No redirect, simple standard public ActionResult View(string id) {... }            It returns a this.view(model)

Answer (score 1):

The button element is treated as submit button (i.e.: type="submit" if not default type attribute is set). Therefore, the browser initiated a post request, which no route satisfied, since all my actions are get(s).

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: good find. advice for future, change your username to something memorable. make a presence on SO. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment

```
http://hspot.ca/course/list
```

matches

```
True    course/list controller = course, action = list
```

but delivers 404. (that is different from your writing, you said this page works).

Such 404 is returned when no controller/action combination can be found that can handle the route and its arguments. Make sure you have a

**CourseController** that has a **List() method** without arguments.

Comment: he does have a list method. I can navigate to it

Comment: ... and there is no parameter on that action. So technically it should be matching.

Comment: now i can too, think there is construction going on. was a guess, when I see 404 and routes match it is mostly such binding problem. To debug the binding step, you can create a dummy binder or you use the mvc4 source, both incurs some work. Any filters like HttpPost attributes or so?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have overcomplicated it a bit.  You really don't need the first two Routes at all, the dafault one alone will do just fine.  Also, I think it is a bad idea to name your action 'view', any chance there is another option?  It is just asking for trouble.

Structure your project like this:

```
Controllers/Course/CourseController.List.cs - Partial with List() method
Controllers/Course/CourseController.View.cs - Partial with View(string id) method

Views/Course/List.cshtml
Views/Course/View.cshtml
```

You should get what you are looking for with much less trouble.

Good luck!!

Comment: I was adding them since nothing was matching... and of course removed them all once i figured the button issue.